# What is the range of pixel values in HSV , YCrCb, and LAB color spaces for each channel in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, colors, rgb, color-space

What is the range of values in HSV, YCrCb and LAB color spaces in opencv python. For example in RGB, R -> 0-255, G -> 0-255 and B -> 0-255. What is the valid range for the mentioned color spaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) covers this completely. Just to recap for your specific questions though, for an 8-bit image, converting from a BGR image with the following conversion codes will give you the following maximum values for each channel:

- `COLOR_BGR2HSV --> [180, 255, 255]`
- `COLOR_BGR2Lab --> [255, 255 255]`
- `COLOR_BGR2YCrCb --> [255, 255 255]`

There's an additional option for the various color transformations that do not get mapped to the full 255 values, generally by appending `_FULL` to the conversion code, so that they use the full range.

For e.g., HLS and HSV colorspaces normally give the H (hue) channel values in `[0, 360)` to map 360 degrees of color on a color wheel. However, you cannot fit those values in a `uint8` type, so instead OpenCV divides this value by 2 with `COLOR_BGR2HSV` or `COLOR_BGR2HLS` so that it fits, but this means you can only specify 180 separate hues in a `uint8` image. But you could fit 255 distinct values, so instead, there exists the options `COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL` and `COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL` (and the inverses) to specify to use the full 255 range for the hue channel; so that 0 maps to 0, 255 maps to 360 degrees, and linearly spaced in between.

All of the available color codes can be seen under the [ColorConversionCodes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0) in the docs.

Comment: not sure about python, but in C++ there is a special conversion code to use the whole 0..255 range for hue channel, too. But afaik that one is rarely used

Comment: @Micka interesting, never seen those before. They exist in Python as well. I will mention them.